# How to persist CSharpCodeProvider generated assembly as byte[]?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

My goals is to generate an assembly using CSharpCodeProvider and then convert it to a byte[] so that it can be stored in a database for later use.

The code I've been trying to use is as follows:

```
public static Assembly Compile(String sourceCode)
{
    var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var parameters = new CompilerParameters();

    parameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
    parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
    parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
    parameters.OutputAssembly = "my.dll";
    parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll");

    CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceCode);
    Assembly assembly = null;

    if (!results.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
        return assembly;
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid source code");
}
```

I've successfully tested the returned assembly using the following:

```
var assembly = SchemaBuilder.Compile(sourceCode); 
var personType = assembly.GetType("app.Person");
object personObject = Activator.CreateInstance(personType);
Assert.IsNotNull(personObject);
```

The problem is that when I convert it to a byte[] and try to load it afterwards I keep getting an exception as if the assembly is being corrupted during conversion:

```
var assembly = SchemaBuilder.Compile(sourceCode);

byte[] dllAsArray;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, assembly);
    dllAsArray = stream.ToArray();
}

Assembly assemblyFromByteArray = Assembly.Load(dllAsArray);
```

**The exception:**

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '171 bytes loaded from builder.test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format.
```

Comment: I would imagine that you first need to deserialize it.

Comment: Deserializing it was exactly what I needed to do.